# Determining disk space usage & file counts for extremely large data sets (any tricks?)

Tags: nfs, hard-drive, disk-space-utilization

Long time reader, first time asker:

I'm a junior-level Linux admin who's increasingly supporting very large data sets/stores on local & NFS storage.  The data is generally in the form of massive folder & file trees with arbitrary names.  To give an example of the challenge, I'm working with 20+ TB partitions containing hundreds of thousands of nested directories and tens of millions of files.

As these partitions/exports are shared resources I generally have to play detective when they begin to run out of space or inodes, to determine what folders are the biggest offenders.

I'm discovering that 'du -s' is much too slow and manual to do the job and was hoping to see what tricks other folks are using to determine the largest or most numerous file count dirs are amongst very large partitions.

The only OS I'm concerned with doing these searches on are RHEL 5/6, so any mix of standard CLI Linux tools is fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest breaking the data up into multiple partitions if that is at all feasible.  No matter what tools you use, scanning through that many files is going to take time.  If it were on separate partitions, you could at least narrow the problem down to a single partition first.  But that may not be an option for what you are doing.

du is likely the best tool for what you are looking for.  Here's how I use it:

If your directory structure looks like:

```
/mount/1/abc/123/456/789, 
/mount/1/def/stuff/morestuff/evenmorestuff
/mount/2/qwer/wer/erty
```

I would run:

```
du -s /mount/*/* | sort -n
```

That will give you the total usage of each second level directory, sorted by size.  If it takes a long time to run, direct it to a file and run it overnight.

Your output will look like this:

```
10000 /mount/1/abc
20000 /mount/1/def
23452 /mount/2/qwer
```

Then you just hope that breaks it down enough to see where the problem spots are.

If this is a regular issue, you could have it run that command every night at a time when your system isn't as busy and save the output to a file.  Then you immediately have some recent data to look at when you notice the problem.

One other option you may wish to look at is quotas - if this is shared storage and they are all using different user accounts, setting very high quotas might work to prevent runaway processes from using gobs of storage space.

Comment: Believe it or not the 15-20TB partitions are smaller chunks of the whole dataset, and are already broken up as much as possible.  I'm currently pointing du at individual dirs a level or two below the top and it's still taking hours and hours to process.  I'm just hoping something faster than du is available.

Comment: Ah.  That's quite the dataset then!  I don't think you'll find anything faster than du.  There may be filesystems that work faster than others for calculating disk space - but that's might be a pretty big undertaking to change.

Answer (score 5):

I make this recommendation often to augment the usual `df -i` and `du -skh` solutions...

Look into the [ncdu utility](http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu). It's an ncurses-based disk utilization graphing tool. You'll get output similar to below with file counts and a summary of directory sizes. It's available for CentOS/RHEL.

Also see: https://serverfault.com/questions/412651/console-utility-to-know-how-disk-space-is-distributed/412655#412655

```
ncdu 1.7 ~ Use the arrow keys to navigate, press ? for help                                                         
--- /data ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  163.3GiB [##########] /docimages                                                                                  
   84.4GiB [#####     ] /data
   82.0GiB [#####     ] /sldata
   56.2GiB [###       ] /prt
   40.1GiB [##        ] /slisam
   30.8GiB [#         ] /isam
   18.3GiB [#         ] /mail
   10.2GiB [          ] /export
    3.9GiB [          ] /edi   
    1.7GiB [          ] /io
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking into that one.  If it's a wrapper for du it probably won't be any faster though.

Comment: [It's not a wrapper for du](http://g.blicky.net/ncdu.git/tree/src/calc.c). And yes, it's faster...

Answer (score 2):

I use this command to check what the largest files are in a dir / on the system. But I'm not sure this is scalable in an environment that you use:

`find / -type f -size +100000k -exec ls -lh {} \; 2>/dev/null| awk '{ print $8 " : " $5}'`

if you want you can leave out the awk statement ( I just use it to clean up the output). 
the find command will recurse trough directories searching for files larger then the given amount k. Then it will execute ls -lh on that file giving something like:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 username group 310K Feb 25  2011 filename
```

the AWK statement cleans up the output in the form of:

```
filename : 310K
```

The thing I find most usefull about this command is the fact that you can specify the minimum size of the files. As said before, I have no idea how CPU / time intensive this is on your environment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I appreciate it.  I like the advantage that find has over du summaries in that find will show results as it finds them.  (I know I could do that with du w/o -s, but that prints too much)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> duc - index, query and graph disk usage
> ```

I like it because of smaller index database file, take a look!

An example of run command:

```
duc index /var/backup -d /var/backup/statistics/duc.db -m7 -p --uncompressed
```

https://duc.zevv.nl/